# Post radio button array to php array variable

Tags: php, html, arrays, post

The problem is I am not able to post inputs from HTML array to php array variable .

X radio button group say answer[1] ,answer[2] .... answer[x].
answer[1] is having four values A,B,C,D selected radio button value to be stored in answer[1] , same for all answer[2], .... answer[x]. So basically I want to store each selected option in array i.e. correct answer for 1 at array location 1 and so on...
I am trying to get answers for objective questions and save it to array variable on submit and then insert in database in single column.

When user enters No. of questions (say 10) he gets  A, B, C, D radio button for each question i.e. 10 times A,B,C,D and can select correct answer and submit.
THen save all answers in array and insert in table .

Html output shows as...

```
<tr>
  <td>1&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="A"> &nbsp A &nbsp <input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="B"> &nbsp B &nbsp<input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="C"> &nbsp C &nbsp <input type="radio" name="answer[1]" value="D">&nbsp D 
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>2&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="A"> &nbsp A &nbsp <input type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="B"> &nbsp B &nbsp<input type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="C"> &nbsp C &nbsp <input type="radio" name="answer[2]" value="D">&nbsp D
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>3&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="answer[3]" value="A"> &nbsp A &nbsp <input type="radio" name="answer[3]" value="B"> &nbsp B &nbsp<input type="radio" name="answer[3]" value="C"> &nbsp C &nbsp <input type="radio" name="answer[3]" value="D">&nbsp D
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td>4&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="answer[4]" value="A"> &nbsp A &nbsp <input type="radio" name="answer[4]" value="B"> &nbsp B &nbsp<input type="radio" name="answer[4]" value="C"> &nbsp C &nbsp <input type="radio" name="answer[4]" value="D">&nbsp D
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>5&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="answer[5]" value="A"> &nbsp A &nbsp <input type="radio" name="answer[5]" value="B"> &nbsp B &nbsp<input type="radio" name="answer[5]" value="C"> &nbsp C &nbsp <input type="radio" name="answer[5]" value="D">&nbsp D
   </td>
       </tr>
```

Php varibale on echo shows Null..
$tq is total number of questions...

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['Submit']))
{ $x=1;
while($tq>=$x) { 
echo "hiii";
$answer_id[] = $_POST['answer[]'] ;$x++;
var_dump( $answer_id[$x]);
}} 
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" onsubmit="javascript:return valpass(this);">
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr >
<td class="page-top-outer"  ><?php include("header_content.php"); ?></td>
</tr>  
<tr>
<td height="500" class="top-inp"><?php include("menu.php"); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php $x=0;
while($tq>0) { $tq--; $x++; 
echo '<tr><td>'.$x.'&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="answer['.$x.']" value="A">&nbsp A &nbsp<input type="radio" name="answer['.$x.']" value="B">&nbsp B &nbsp<input type="radio" name="answer['.$x.']" value="C">&nbsp C&nbsp<input type="radio" name="answer['.$x.']" value="D">&nbsp D</td></tr>';

}
?>
<input name="Submit" type="Submit" value="Submit">
</table>
```

Output is 5 times null if $tq=5.

Answer (score 2):

The `$_POST` will be like -

```
array(
    answer => array(
               1 => value1,
               2 => value2,
               .......
              )
)
```

Try with -

```
$answers = $_POST['answer'];
foreach ($answers as $answer) {
    var_dump($answer);
}
```

Comment: Tried output when tq is 4 is:  string(1) "A" string(1) "C" string(1) "D" string(1) "D"

Comment: With this method you dont even need `$tq` as `foreach` will loop till the last element.

Comment: yes, while is not needed thank u. Now how to store this value as array in table column 'correct ans' ...
I tried to insert but in table it shows 'array' as value inserted..

Comment: it will depend on your table structure. Though you can run the query inside the loop and store them.

Comment: I have a single field where i want to store as associative array so that I could later check with students answer array ...
store like :   s:1:"D";s:2:"C";s:3:"D";s:4:"A";

Comment: Used serialize but it saves only 1 value :  s:1:"D";

Comment: if you wnat the serialized data to save then whay are you running the loop. ?? Just serialize the `answer` and save it.

Comment: Done , by adding $ans_val=serialize($answers);
   
   
   $ins = "UPDATE question_paper SET `correct_ans`='$ans_val' Where `id` = '$paperid'"; //exit;
   $zz  = mysql_query($ins);

Answer (score 0):

Can you update the code like this and try:

**HTML**

```
<tr>
  <td>1&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="answer1[]" value="A"> &nbsp A &nbsp
      <input type="radio" name="answer1[]" value="B"> &nbsp B &nbsp
      <input type="radio" name="answer1[]" value="C"> &nbsp C &nbsp 
      <input type="radio" name="answer1[]" value="D">&nbsp D 
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>2&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="answer2[]" value="A"> &nbsp A &nbsp 
       <input type="radio" name="answer2[]" value="B"> &nbsp B &nbsp
       <input type="radio" name="answer2[]" value="C"> &nbsp C &nbsp 
       <input type="radio" name="answer2[]" value="D">&nbsp D
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>3&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="answer3[]" value="A"> &nbsp A &nbsp 
        <input type="radio" name="answer3[]" value="B"> &nbsp B &nbsp
        <input type="radio" name="answer3[]" value="C"> &nbsp C &nbsp 
        <input type="radio" name="answer3[]" value="D">&nbsp D
    </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td>4&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="answer4[]" value="A"> &nbsp A &nbsp 
       <input type="radio" name="answer4[]" value="B"> &nbsp B &nbsp
       <input type="radio" name="answer4[]" value="C"> &nbsp C &nbsp 
       <input type="radio" name="answer4[]" value="D">&nbsp D
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>5&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type="radio" name="answer5[]" value="A"> &nbsp A &nbsp 
       <input type="radio" name="answer5[]" value="B"> &nbsp B &nbsp
       <input type="radio" name="answer5[]" value="C"> &nbsp C &nbsp 
       <input type="radio" name="answer5[]" value="D">&nbsp D
   </td>
       </tr>
```

**PHP**

```
$answer1 = $_POST['answer1'];
$answer2 = $_POST['answer2'];
$answer3 = $_POST['answer3'];
$answer4 = $_POST['answer4'];
$answer5 = $_POST['answer5'];
```